# SELECT QUERY FROM three tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

my tables look like this:

**news**

```
id_news
id_gallery
headline
content
date
```

**galleries**

```
id_gallery
gallery_name
```

**images**

```
id_image
id_gallery
```

And I need to select every image for certain news. I am very unfamiliar with sql, so I would really appreciate every kind of help. I have searched, but when I try to use queries that I find, it just doesn't work, I'm doing something really wrong.. Help!

Thank you for Your time

Comment: You really need to learn SQL or hire a programmer. You can't expect to find everything you need already written, or get randoms on the Internet to do your coding for you for free.

Comment: Wanna hire me for some "quick'n'easy"-tasks? :D

Comment: You need to do a join on these tables to merge the and filter out to get the ones you want.

Comment: You need to use an inner join and possibly two if you want the name of the gallery.  Research that if you haven't already and then show us what you think it should be.  We can then use that as a starting point to help you fix your code and your thinking, rather than just doing it for you.

Comment: will do that, thank you

Comment: If you have searched and found thing that you think should work but don't post that here. Or better yet use sqlfiddle.com to create a minimal replica of your data along with the failed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM images AS i
JOIN news AS n on n.id_gallery = i.id_gallery
WHERE n.id_news = <selected news>
```

Comment: BTW, as you can see, only two tables are needed. You're not using anything from the `galleries` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM images a
JOIN news b on b.id_gallery = a.id_gallery
```

Hope this helps. :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but I need you need something like this:

```
select i.id_image
from news n
    left outer join images i on n.id_gallery = i.id_gallery
where n.id_news = 1 -- Or for whichever news id the images are needed
```

Comment: Why do you use a left join? This will return a null image if the news doesn't have any images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
select id_news, id_gallery from news join images on images.id_gallary=news.id_gallery
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
a) SELECT something : SELECT images.id_image
b) FROM the table images : FROM images
d) Where the id_gallery on news is the same as the id_gallery on images : 
   JOIN news on image.id_gallery = news.id_gallery
e) But not all news, only ceratain news: WHERE news.id_news > 100 (Could use other criteria)

All together
 SELECT images.id_image, images.id_gallery 
 FROM images
 JOIN news on image.id_gallery = news.id_gallery
 WHERE news.id_news > 100

Another way to do it (implicit join) is:
  SELECT images.id_image, images.id_gallery 
 FROM  images,news
 WHERE (image.id_gallery = news.id_gallery) AND (news.id_news > 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select rows from one table based on a column in another, you have to use a join.

So lets just say you are trying to select all images linked to an existing news.

```
 select * 
 from images i inner join news n on i.id_gallery = n.id_gallery
```

This will return all the columns on all the rows where an image can be linked to a news.